# TS Observable & ng: proper templating syntax

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, templating

I have an observable "applicationDetail" (`private applicationDetail: Observable<ApplicationDetail>;`). I bind the values like this:

```
<h2 class="detailViewH2">{{ (applicationDetail | async)?.AttendeeName }}</h2>
<p>{{ (applicationDetail | async)?.AttendeeFunction }} </p>
```

This doesn't seem like proper templating syntax to me, isn't there a way to generally say "applicationDetail" will be async and all it's props should use the safe navigation operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular4 you can work around this using `*ngIf`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(applicationDetail | async) as foo">
  <h2 class="detailViewH2">{{foo.AttendeeName }}</h2>
  <p>{{foo.AttendeeFunction }} </p>
</ng-container>
```

You can also create your own structural directive that doesn't remove the content when the expression is false but otherwise provides this functionality.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK only V4+.

Comment: Do you know how to use it with two variables? Using `(expr1) && (expr2)` doesn't work. Using two `ng-container`s works, is quite ugly though.

Comment: Perhapse `<ng-container *ngIf="{a: applicationDetail | async, b: bar | async }  as foo">{{foo.a.AttendeeName}} {{foo.b.bar}}</div>`. Not tried myself yet though. This would also prevent `*ngIf` to remove the content, because the value would always be truthy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)